# I want just one timeajax request

Tags: jquery

It always requests when the page scrolls, but I want just one request per page.

Here is my code:

```
function loadLikeMoreVideos(category_id) {
        $('.like-more-videos').html();
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            // if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            if($(window).scrollTop()) {
                $.post('<?php echo base_url('watch/ajax/get_more_videos'); ?>',{category_id: category_id},function(e){
                if(e.status=='success'){
                    $('.like-more-videos').html(e.html);
                }
                if(typeof callback === 'function'){
                    callback();
                }
            });
            }
        });
        
    }
```

Comment: per page as in once per page load or once per full page scroll?

Comment: Just load one time when scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a `variable` in the `global scope` and then set that to `false` once the `first ajax` has been sent.

As shown below

```js
var canAjax = true;
function loadLikeMoreVideos(category_id) {
        $('.like-more-videos').html();
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            // if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            if($(window).scrollTop()) {

                if(canAjax){ // Check if we can send ajax
                canAjax = false; // We're sending ajax, so the if statement above will fail if we try again
                
                $.post('<?php echo base_url('watch/ajax/get_more_videos'); ?>', 
                    {category_id: category_id},function(e){
                    if(e.status=='success'){
                        $('.like-more-videos').html(e.html);
                    }
                    if(typeof callback === 'function'){
                        callback();
                    }
                });
                }
             }
        });
        
    }
```

If you need to send `another` ajax request after a set distance of scrolling, simply save the `window.scrollY` to a variable and then compare that with the new `window.scrollY` when the user scrolls again, check to see, for example, the new value - old value is > 600 (therefore 600px has passed) and we can ajax again.